How can a creature use an Action to escape a Bag of Devouring?
The Bag of Devouring says the following:

A creature inside the bag can take an action to try to escape, doing so with a successful DC 15 Strength (Athletics) check. Another creature can take an action to reach into the bag to pull a creature out, doing so with a successful DC 20 Strength (Athletics) check, provided the puller isn’t pulled inside the bag first. Any creature that starts its turn inside the bag is devoured, its body destroyed.

Given that starting your turn inside the bag results in instant death, how could one use an Action to escape it?
It seems like realistically, the only potential means of escape is for an ally to attempt to pull you out (at significant risk no less).

Upon arrival in the bag, you likely have an action available
Suppose you reach into the bag, attempting to retrieve an item.  You might be successful, for the bag can hold (non-edible) items for up to a day.  However, there is a 50% chance you will be pulled in yourself rather than you pulling out an item.  At that point, the crucial question is whether you have already used your action this turn.  If your action is still available, you can immediately try to escape, as described.  If your action has already been used, however, you are in the bag until the start of your next turn, unless someone else can pull you out.
You might think that reaching into the bag was itself your action, and maybe you thought that because that is how a bag of holding works:

Retrieving an item from the bag requires an action.

However, a careful reading of the bag of devouring reveals that no action is required to retrieve an item from it.  It explicitly states that an action is required to attempt escape, or to attempt to pull a creature out.  But it does not say that "when someone reaches inside it" to attempt to remove an item, an action is required.  Because there is no specific rule here, we default to the general rule for pulling an object out of any bag - which is that it is free so long as it is the first object you have interacted with this turn:

Your turn can include a variety of flourishes that require neither your action nor your move...
You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or your action. For example, you could open a door during your move as you stride toward a foe, or you could draw your weapon as part of the same action you use to attack.

See also the "Interacting with objects around you" sidebar, which gives examples of free object interactions including "withdraw a potion from your backpack" and "fish a few coins from your belt pouch".
Thus, your interrupted attempt to pull an object from the bag does not use an action (and would not have done so even if you had been successful).  You likely still have an action available to attempt escape.
If not, you might have some kind of protection
If you had already used your action before reaching into the bag, if you had already used your free object interaction on your turn such that reaching into the bag was your action, or if your first attempt to escape the bag was unsuccessful, then you will be starting your next turn in the bag, and would normally be devoured before your action was available that turn to attempt escape.
The bag of devouring says:

Any creature that starts its turn inside the bag is devoured, its body destroyed.

However, a potential victim might have some measure of protection, such as a death ward, which says, in part:

If the spell is still in effect when the target is subjected to an effect that would kill it instantly without dealing damage, that effect is negated against the target, and the spell ends.

A creature with an active death ward would otherwise be killed by the bag without taking damage.  The death ward would then trigger at the start of the turn, negating that turn's devouring and providing one round of protection.  The creature could then use its action on its turn to attempt escape.  If escape was unsuccessful, it would be devoured at the start of its next turn, absent another form of protection.
Besides death ward, other effects that protect from instant death might also work, depending on their wording.

If this were RAI, wouldn’t they have put the “Any creature that starts its turn…” clause at the beginning of the description? And, wouldn’t they note that, if the creature was protected somehow, then it could use an action?

@nonymous No, I don't think the order of the item description was written with death ward in mind.  Rather, the order given follows logically from: when you reach inside, you might be pulled in.  When you are pulled in, you might escape.  When you don't escape, you are devoured.  Edited to reflect this.  Thank you.

Sounds good , I removed my down vote since I agree with the more recent edit. Though, now we’re saying almost the same thing. :)

@nonymous Yes, and I am indebted to your answer and comment for making me realize that there was more to the question and situation than I had seen before.  I do think they are distinct answers, though, since you contend that the action is not used because the act of retrieval was aborted, whereas I argue that the action was never needed to begin with.

Not aborted, “never actually taken”

You must use the Action on your turn, which is the same turn that you are devoured.
The wording on this item's description is terrible, but RAW being inside the bag enables you to take an action to try to escape--independent of turn mechanics.

A creature inside the bag can take an action to try to escape...

Thus, any creature can technically take that action before the start of its turn. However, this conclusion feels awkward because it doesn't fit into conventional initiative mechanics. If you wanted to map this on to conventional mechanics, you may have to make some adjustments to the RAW.
It would be reasonable to assume that anyone in this situation has already taken the Utilize action to try to retrieve an item from the bag, and so has no action economy left with which to attempt to escape. However, since interacting with the Bag of Devouring is not equivalent to interacting with a Bag of Holding, the Utilize action is never actually taken, and the action economy is never expended.
It is reasonable to conclude, then, that the act of attempting to retrieve something from the Bag of Devouring does not require an action, so the devoured character can instead use their action to attempt to escape.

A creature inside the bag can take an action to try to escape, doing so with a successful DC 15 Strength (Athletics) check.

This would map onto initiative action economy under the following paradigm:

Character attempts to retrieve something from the bag.
Extra-dimensional monster uses a special Reaction to grapple/drag the creature into the bag (instead of a contested check, 50% chance of success).
Character instead uses an Action to try to escape.
Character expends remaining action economy.
Other characters may act as though in a round of Combat, presumably to help their ally get out of the bag.
If Character starts the next turn inside the bag, it is devoured.

Either of these two approaches is almost certainly covers the RAI, though I have to agree with you that the RAW could be very punishing if your DM is unforgiving.
Further considerations...
It's not clear when exactly it is necessary to put an appendage inside the Bag of Devouring, either. Is it only necessary for retrieval, or does an attempt to store an object also require reaching into the bag? Apparently, this is up to DM fiat.
I might make the suggestion that the RAW,

When part of a living creature is placed in the bag, as happens when someone reaches inside it, there is a 50 percent chance that the creature is pulled inside the bag. A creature inside the bag can take an action to try to escape, doing so with a successful DC 15 Strength (Athletics) check. ... Any creature that starts its turn inside the bag is devoured, its body destroyed.

should be scrapped in lieu of something like,

When part of a living creature is placed in the bag, as happens when a creature reaches inside it, either in an attempt to place an object into the bag or retrieve an item from it, that creature must make successful DC 15 Strength (Athletics) check, or be pulled into the bag. ... Any creature that starts its turn inside the bag is devoured, its body destroyed.

Finally, any savvy adventurer should always use a safe/creative method to put a vegetable (not an animal, you monsters!) inside any apparent Bag of Holding, and leave it there for a few minutes before turning the bag inside out. Since any

Animal or vegetable matter placed wholly in the bag is devoured and lost forever...

you can generally conclude that the bag is safe to use if the vegetable is still there. Alternatively, if able, add some kind of protection, e.g. Death Ward, as Kirt suggests.
